# How can I sync slugs within sites in the same Group?

Tags: craft3, localization, slug, sites

I have a Craft site with approx. 13 Sites. They are grouped by language, e.g. German has Germany and Austria in it. Spanish has Spain and Mexico in it.

I imported all content to the main groups sites as the other fields are all set to be translatable per group. So importing Spain means Mexico will have the same content.

But the slugs are not synced. The slugs still use the original English slugs from when I cerated the sites.

How can I get the slugs to sync. within the group? So Mexico slugs will take Spanish slugs?

Thanks

Comment: Slugs are created when you create entry and won't be changed unless you change them manually. You can also remove slug for specific entry and resave it - slug will be re-created from current entry title.

Comment: But I have set all other fields including the title (via a custom field) to be the same within a group. Extremely strange you cant do the same for a slug. I have imported all this foreign content and the slugs are all english except for the main site in the group I imported.

Comment: Are you using feedme plugin to import? If thats the case, i retract what i said later - i have no experience using this plugin so i cant say for sure if slug cam be changed in that case or not.

Comment: Yes FeedMe but even changing it afterwards does not sync them. There is no option to keep them the sane like customs fields. I’ve written a function in my plugin to sync them in the database after import and an after save event so will add my code here soon.